# Japaneses maple

Tags: japanese-maple

I have a big beautiful Japanese  maple by my deck which gives us shade but the seeds helicopter looking seeds are falling all over my deck and table which I sweep up all the time. When do the seeds stop falling.
Sara Mastrull

Comment: Depends where you are in the world to some extent... in the UK, they've more or less finished falling